# Are two tracks technically related?

Tags: piano, motif

I was choosing a theme for my alarm and found [Springtide](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zs5FqzIt1Y), reminded me of [Road to Perdition](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_to_Perdition) the movie. Particularly the [Road to Chicago](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvpsTBjqxxk) track, after I had checked the soundtrack in [YouTube](//youtu.be).

So maybe this is for [Music Fans](//musicfans.stackexchange.com) but from here I'll try the minimum effort I can think of in order to try to fit it in here.

Thinking about the reason for connection.
I'm surprised that the tempo seems very different to me, and one track features bells and the other strings. I've considered that an obvious rebirth motif might be the reason for a personal, subjective connection.

However is there any music-technical non trivial connection between the two tracks as well, maybe fuelling that up? Like; notes, chords, key, time separation between particular chords, progressions, etc?

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing technically connecting the two tracks, but I do think whoever composed the alarm tune was aiming halfway between Thomas Neuman and Trent Reznor's recent soundtrack work.  That's probably what you're hearing: a vague stylistic influence without directly copying any particular aspect of their work.